# Firebaseui with Ionic framework not working on android

Tags: android, firebase, ionic-framework, firebase-authentication, firebaseui

I used [firebaseui](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/firebaseui) to use firebase authentication in my app everything works fine while using on the web, However when I try to run it on an android device it fails (goes to the google authentication page then it doesn't redirect me back to the application)
Here is my config

```
const uiConfig = {
    signInOptions: [
      auth.GoogleAuthProvider.PROVIDER_ID,
      {
        provider: 'yahoo.com',
        providerName: 'Yahoo',
        buttonColor: '#720E9E',
      },
      auth.FacebookAuthProvider.PROVIDER_ID,
      {
        provider: auth.PhoneAuthProvider.PROVIDER_ID,
        defaultCountry: 'EG',
      },
      auth.TwitterAuthProvider.PROVIDER_ID,
    ],
    signInFlow: 'popup',
    callbacks: {
      signInSuccessWithAuthResult: function (authResult) {
        _this.authService.updateStatusOnLogin(authResult.user);
        return false;
      },
    },
  };
```

does anyone has an idea how to make it works on an android device ?

Comment: Could you be more specific about what is actually happening here, and how that's different than what you expect?  Please describe clearly.  Note that signInFlow of "redirect" is stated in the documentation as more appropriate for mobile.

Comment: What happens is when trying to authenticate using android device it goes to the google popup then upon choosing the account it views a blank screen with no more actions and no authentication has been done.

Comment: Also when I tried the redirect sign in flow from the android device it redirects me back to localhost, I don't know how to configure it

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if you solved this yet, I'm having the same problem I'll be trying this next week.
https://www.npmjs.com/package/cordova-plugin-firebaseui-auth

Comment: Is anything in your post actually answering the question?